# Пример работы быстрой сортировки за O(n^2)

Tags: c++, сортировка

Каким образом можно сгенерировать тест, на котором `std::sort` будет работать за `O(n^2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зависит от реализации. Смотрите в реализацию вашего `std::sort` и танцуйте от этого. Классическими примерами, "ломающими" общие алгоримы быстрой сортировки являются

1. Набор из всего двух классов элементов. Т.е., например, сортировка последовательности из 0 и 1. В такой последовательности, по понятным причинам, нет хорошей медианы. Поэтому не рассчитанные специально на такой вход алгоритмы зачастую начинают вести себя плохо.
2. Вход вида "две горки"

   ```
        *     *
       **    **
      ***   ***
     ****  ****
    ***** *****
   ************
   ```

   Такой вход мешает алгоритмам выбора медианы типа "один из трех" получить хорошую медиану. Удастся ли алгоритму выбрать лучшую медиану на более глубоких уровнях рекурсии зависит от реализации.

Comment: Насколько знаю обычно там вариант timsort.

Comment: Проверил оба варианта . На наборах из 0 и 1 и `sort()` и `qsort()` опережают `merge sort` а вот для "горок" наблюдается прогресс . Для `10^6` элементов  `merge sort` работает `405` мс , `sort()- 436` , `qsort()- 561` . И хотя об `O(n^2)` речь не идет , это все же больше чем `O(n log n)`

Answer (score 4):

`std::sort` - использует другой алгоритм сортировки и всегда работает за O(n*ln(n)).

Быстрая сортировка - это `qsort` из `cstdlib`.

Алгоритм выбора опорного элемента может быть разным в разных компиляторах, поэтому подобрать последовательность, гарантированно дающую квадратичное время не представляется возможным.

Можно попробовать через `next_permutation` измерить время всех сортировок и уже на основе полученных результатов выбрать структуру последовательности.

Comment: Никто никогда не гарантировал, что `qsort` в библиотеке С реализует какой-то фиксированный канонический алгоритм быстрой сортировки. На самом деле нет никакой разницы в подобного рода гарантиях от `std::sort` и от `qsort`.

Comment: @AnT, насколько я помню, std::sort гарантирует ассимптотику. А что ты подразумеваешь под фиксированным каноническим алгоритмом, я вообще не понимаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Судя по всему, то, что `qsort` не обязательно реализован как quicksort, несмотря на название? (Я лично не в курсе.)

Comment: @VladD,  ubuntu eglibc (стандартно идет она) qsort при достаточном количестве RAM реализует сортировку слиянием (устойчивую), а вот если памяти мало (конкретный лимит не помню, какой-то процент от RAM), то quicksort (как известно, неустойчивую  сортировку). Такая, вот, засада.

Comment: @avp: Ничего себе! Не знал, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если там quicksort, то массив, отсортированный в обратную сторону, даст ожидаемое время исполнения O(n^2). Если там mergesort, то нельзя такой создать, у него худший случай O(n*log(n)).